# radio кнопки на css для слайдера

Tags: css

Как правильно сделать кнопки под слайдер чтобы при нажатии(checked) менялся фон у этой кнопки, а у остальных не менялся?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hello</title>
    <style>
    .hello_world input{
        display: none;
    }
    .hello_world label{
        display: inline-block;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 2px solid black;
        background: #aaa;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 50px;
    }

    #button1:checked ~ #hw1{
        background: #fff;
    }
    #button1:checked ~ #hw2{
        background: #fff;
    }
    #button1:checked ~ #hw3{
        background: #fff;
    }
    #button1:checked ~ #hw4{
        background: #fff;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="hello_world">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button1">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button2">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button3">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button4">
    <label id="hw1" for="button1"></label>
    <label id="hw2" for="button2"></label>
    <label id="hw3" for="button3"></label>
    <label id="hw4" for="button4"></label>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1

```css
.hello_world input {
  display: none;
}
.hello_world label {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 50px;
}
#button1:checked ~ #hw1,
#button2:checked ~ #hw2,
#button3:checked ~ #hw3,
#button4:checked ~ #hw4 {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello_world">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button1" checked >
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button3">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button4">
  <label id="hw1" for="button1"></label>
  <label id="hw2" for="button2"></label>
  <label id="hw3" for="button3"></label>
  <label id="hw4" for="button4"></label>
</div>
```

Вариант 2

```css
[id^=button]{
  display: none;
}
[id^=button] + label{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 50px;
}
[id^=button]:checked + label{
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello_world">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button1" checked >
  <label id="hw1" for="button1"></label>
  
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button2">
  <label id="hw2" for="button2"></label>
  
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button3">
  <label id="hw3" for="button3"></label>
  
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button4">  
  <label id="hw4" for="button4"></label>
</div>
```

Пример со слайдером

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hello_world {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
[id^=button] {
  display: none;
}
[id^=button] + label {
  position: relative;
  top: 195px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99;
}
[id^=button]:checked + label {
  background: #fff;
}
[id^=button] + label ~ [id^=slider-content-] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 35px auto;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  line-height: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
#button1:checked + label ~ #slider-content-1,
#button2:checked + label ~ #slider-content-2,
#button3:checked + label ~ #slider-content-3,
#button4:checked + label ~ #slider-content-4 {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
#button2:checked + label ~ #slider-content-2 {
  background: #FAEBD7;
}
#button3:checked + label ~ #slider-content-3 {
  background: #8FBC8F;
}
#button4:checked + label ~ #slider-content-4 {
  background: #F0E68C;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello_world">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button1" checked>
  <label id="hw1" for="button1"></label>
  <div id="slider-content-1">
    <h2>slider-content-1</h2>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button2">
  <label id="hw2" for="button2"></label>
  <div id="slider-content-2">
    <h2>slider-content-2</h2>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button3">
  <label id="hw3" for="button3"></label>
  <div id="slider-content-3">
    <h2>slider-content-3</h2>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="button4">
  <label id="hw4" for="button4"></label>
  <div id="slider-content-4">
    <h2>slider-content-4</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```